# Geneal B+ Tree split logic

Tags: b-tree

I just want to know if you would split a leaf node after the insert or before the insert. lets say our capacity in the leaf is 4 elements and we already have 3 elements in there. would you add the 4th element and immediately split after the insert so we have now two nodes holding 2 elements each. Or would you just add the 4th element so that the leaf is full. Now if you add the 5th element (which would cause an overflow) we do the split and add the element which would result in 2 leaf nodes one holding 2 and one holding 3 elements.

EDIT: Since I have seed both approaches out there in the www. I would like to know the reason when to choose solution 1 or 2. Or if one of them even is incorrect for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/BPlusTree.html

This visualization is very useful to understand B+ tree logic.

Comment: I know this visualisation but this is completely different from this tutorial: http://sliit-help.blogspot.ch/2012/12/b-tree-tutorial_5.html so here you can see exact why this question is comming up. the visual do it like  I have explained in the first and the tutorial does it like I have explained secondly. so there must be reasons to choose solution 1 or 2.

Comment: I am not sure if this visualization is correct anyway. You could add for example two equal nodes which should not be possible. and on a capacity of 4 the do a very wired split to 1 / 3

Comment: You're right. Visualisation is wrong. Sorry for inconvenience. The answer of your question is split after adding the fifth one.